# Detect when item is swiped in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'd like to know when an item was swiped in a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) (vs standard selection)

The `ListView` has a [`IsSwipeEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isswipeenabled.Aspx) property, which turns the swipe animation on/off, but I cant seem to figure out how to detect when an item was actually swiped, nor can I find any event that seems to provide this.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this was down voted.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to monitor the manipulation events and create your own "Swipe" event by tracking the velocity of the gestures, or create your own kind of listitem.

And example of the latter is located [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2c3c208b-05b7-4431-a41e-e1ce06256fb3/listview-swipe-left-right-on-an-item?forum=winappswithcsharp)

If you need assistance with a more specific portion of the implementation, response to this post and I will revise my answer accordingly.

Also, don't forget to read up on [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.crosssliding.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) if you haven't already.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll take a closer look at them and give them a shot. One thing I didnt mention was that I did try to do my own manipulation detection by setting the mode to TranslateX - but the issue I encountered was that it drastically made the listview very hard to scroll, since my manipulation event seemed to be eating up part of the touch for the scroll. Maybe GestureRecognizer gets around this? I am surprised this isnt built into listview, given its 'partial' support of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Override `OnManipulationDelta` for list view item to get cumulative and delta position.

I have a super list view library for uwp include swipe function : https://github.com/brookshi/LLMListView

Comment: I like you control I used "Normal Fix Page" thanks :) keep it up